# bootstrap4: flex : align-content-center not working

Tags: bootstrap-4

I want the span item inside a div to be vertically centered in a flex container. I am using bootstrap4

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/

using `align-content-center` and `justify-content-center`. Looks like `justify-content-center` is working well, whereas `align-content-center` not

```
<div class="col-12">
        <div class="d-flex  align-content-center justify-content-center p-2">
        <div class="p-2">
            <span>Warm Weather Shutdown</span>
        </div>
        <div  class="p-2">
            <input type="checkbox">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can do this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `align-content-center`, `align-items-center` worked for me.

```
<div class="col-12">
        <div class="d-flex  align-items-center justify-content-center p-2">
        <div class="p-2">
            <span>Warm Weather Shutdown</span>
        </div>
        <div  class="p-2">
            <input type="checkbox">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```